# Php form with radio button does not work

Tags: php, forms

i have html form with php.
everything is working fine, except radio button. when i get email the Contact info is blank.

i have some error in php file. Pls help me

HTML:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="form.php">
    <table width="450px">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"">
                <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"">
                <label class="radio" for="txtContact">Preferred Method of Contact</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input class="radio" type="radio" name="contact" value="email" checked /> <span>Email</span>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" name="contact" value="phone" /> <span>Phone</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "mmukaetov@yahoo.com";
    $email_subject = "Нарачка";
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['contact']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact: ".clean_string($contact)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>
    <!-- include your own success html here -->
    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: As far as i can see you use `$contact` but aren't writing something to it...

Comment: Not related to the question: You have an error `<td valign="top"">` should be `<td valign="top">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing `$contact = $_POST['contact'];`!

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not assign value in `$contact` variable

```
   $contact = $_POST['contact']; // radio button value
```